# Unit test: Check which expression was passed into method in test

Tags: c#, nunit, rhino-mocks

I am currently looking into how best to test the below piece of code, where the same method gets called, by just with a different expression.

```
if (boolResult)
{
    service.Update(
        x => x.Id == newId && x.Version == version,
        x => new Foo
        {
            FooId = newId,
            OtherProp = otherValue
        });
}
else if (some other scenario)
{
    service.Update(x => x.Id == newId,
        x => new Foo
        {
            FooId = newId
        });
}
```

In the unit test, I would like to Assert that the `service.Update` call is run with the expected expression.  What I would like to achieve is something like the below:

```
//set up the expressions
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expression = x => x.Id == newId && x.Version <= newVersion;
Expression<Func<Foo, Foo>> updateExpression = x => new Foo
{
    Id = newId,
    OtherProp = otherValue
};

//assert
m_service.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Update(Arg<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>.Is.Equal(expression), Arg<Expression<Func<Foo, Foo>>>.Is.Equal(updateExpression)));
```

This fails, but wondering whether this approach is correct, and how best to check that the correct expressions have been passed into the function.
Note that in the test, `m_service` is a `MockRepository.GenerateMock<IService>();`

Answer (score 1):

Don't verify the internals of the unit under test; verify its effects instead.

One expression does something the other doesn't: it updates the other property. Verify that this property is updated.